# Determine if an Index has been used as a hint

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, query-hints

In SQL Server, there is the option to use query hints. 
eg

```
SELECT c.ContactID
FROM Person.Contact c
WITH (INDEX(AK_Contact_rowguid))
```

I am in the process of getting rid of unused indexes and was wondering how I could go about determining if an index was used as a query hint.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I could do this?

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: Are you asking whether the index was ever used in a hint (including ad-hoc SQL Statements) or just if it is used in a view/proc?

Comment: I want ot know if the index was used in a view/proc.  My concern is that if a remove an index that is used as a hint in a view/proc the view/proc will fail when called by the DB app, which ultimately means the end user will get some unexpected error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only run profiler for client SQL or search `sys.sql_modules` otherwise.

To find unused indexes you'd normally use [something based on dmvs](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=unused+index+dmv+script). This would show you what indexes are in use and need to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question, and I don't think I can give you an easy answer.  If it were me, I would script th entire database in Management Studio and do a Text search for the index name.  I would also do that in all of my reports and source code, just to be sure, too.

I don't think that hints make their way to sys.dependencies for procs an functions, but even if they did, you'd have some ad-hoc SQL to potentially deal with, so that's why I'd use the text searching route.

Comment: How would I go about scripting the entire DB?  There is an option in SSMS to script DB but this only creates a script for the DB and not the DB objects.

Comment: I have put this project on hold but for anyone who is interested here is a link for scripting SQL Server 2008 DBs.  

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-script-database-by-sql-2008-script-wizard.aspx

I haven't tried it out but it looks like it would do the job.